# Mapstruct not generating implementations with Maven and Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, maven, mapstruct

as you've read in the title, I have a problem using Mapstruct with Kotlin and Maven.

(FYI: The solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465747/mapstruct-is-not-generating-implementation-classes) didn't resolve the issue for me).

Following [mapstruct-examples/mapstruct-kotlin](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/main/mapstruct-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/org/mapstruct/example/kotlin/converter/PersonConverter.kt), I've added the `kapt plugin` alongside the dependency to my project-roots `<pluginManagement>`:

```xml
<!-- Cut out non-kapt executions -->
<execution>
    <id>kapt</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>kapt</goal>
    </goals>

    <configuration>
        <sourceDirs>
            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
        </sourceDirs>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version> <!-- :1.5.5.Final -->
            </annotationProcessorPath>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Then I use it in each sub module like so:

```xml
<!-- Cut out unnecessary stuff again -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Just in case it helps clearing some questions, here's the Mapper:

```java
@Mapper
interface CustomMapper {

    fun toDTO(entity: Entity): DTO

    fun toEntity(dto: DTO): Entity
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was rather easy to pull off and had an even dumber source to begin with.

The app I used Mapstruct in was a multi module project. Two of these modules depended on each other => Thus there was a cyclic dependency.

I refactored the modules to not be dependent on one and each other and that seemed to solve the issue.